# How to check Type of structure in C

Tags: c

I made a simple listing struct in C that holds any kind of data using void* pointer, something like:

```
struct node
{
    void *the_data;
    node *next;
};
```

It is working just fine, but I have some lists that contains, for example, only struct_a in a list and only struct_b in another list. I need to check if the first element of the list is of struct_a type or struct_b type in a single if() question so I know the data that this list is holding. How to do this? Thanks

**Edit:**

I've come up with a simple solution that is enough for the problem now, dunno if it's the best:

```
struct node
{
    void *data;
    node *next;
}
```

And I added a "descriptor" node, which contains the address of the first node and info about the type:

```
struct list_desc
{
    node *list;
    short int type;
}
```

and I'll use it with some macros like

```
#define __data_type1 10
#define __data_type2 20
```

so later I can compare like if( struct.type == __data_tipe1 ) etc...

Comment: add a type field so you can record what the pointer is actually pointing at? a void pointer is just that... a memory address with no clue as to what's really there.

Comment: Do you mean the `the_data` can point to different types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you think about that:

```
typedef enum tag_ElementType
{
    ElementA,
    ElementB
} en_ElementType;

typedef struct tag_Container
{
    en_ElementType ElementType;
    void *pData;
} st_Container;
```

In this case your structure will look like this:

```
typedef struct tag_node
{
    st_Container the_data;
    struct tag_node *next;
} st_node;
```

Answer (score 6):

C does not provide run-time type information. You have to add this information yourself. There are two basic approaches (assuming C99 or C11):

You can use a struct (potentially) with anonymous union:

```
struct Node {
    enum {
        OBJ_TYPE_A,
        OBJ_TYPE_B
    } type;
    union {
        struct NodeA a;
        struct NodeB b;
    };    // anonymous, if a name is added, you have an additional field name
};

...

struct Node *node = ...;

if ( node->type == OBJ_TYPE_A ) {

    node->a.a_field = whatever;

...
```

Cons are you have to define the union in a single place and cannot extend this in another module.

---

A better approach is to build a true class-hierarchy with anonymous structs:

```
struct Node {
    enum {
        OBJ_TYPE_A,
        OBJ_TYPE_B
    } type;
    struct Node *next;
};

struct NodeA {
    struct Node;    // base class, first field!
    int a_field;
};

struct NodeB {
    struct Node;    // base class, first field!
    float b_field;
};

void take_node(struct Node *node)
    // takes a generic pointer to the base-class
{

    if ( node->type == OBJ_TYPE_A ) {
        struct NodeA *a_node = (NodeA)node;
        a_node->a_field = whatever;
    } else if ...

    ...

}

// until here that is normal C99

int main(void)
{
    struct NodeA anode = { .type = OBJ_TYPE_A, .a_field = 42 };
    struct NodeB bnode = { .type = OBJ_TYPE_B, .b_field = 4.2 };
    take_node((Node *)&anode);    // standard: inhibits type checking
    take_node(&anode);    // plan9-extension: no cast required
    take_node(&bnode);    // plan9-extension: no cast required
}
```

Pro is there is no need to extend the base struct (it does not depend on the child structs) when creating new child structs. The anonymous structs allow to create children of the direct children and access fields as one would expect in OOP (no chain of field specifiers: `child1_1_1_ptr->child1_1.child1.base.base_field`, but just `child1_1_1_ptr->base_field`).

The latter two invocations of `take_node` uses the gcc C-extension `-fplan9-extensions`. This avoids to cast to the base-class while still enabling type-checking (base class or a child). This is a large step towards OOP already.

That can be extended to a full size OOP approach, including virtual methods. However, there is a point using a true OOPL like C++ becomes easier.

Answer (score 3):

C doesn't contain any runtime information about what a pointer is pointing to.  You can create a struct containing a type field and a union containing whatever else you'd like to store.

```
enum node_type {
    NODE_TYPE_STRING,
    NODE_TYPE_INT,
    NODE_TYPE_DOUBLE,
    NODE_TYPE_OTHER_STRUCT
};

struct other_struct {
    // define some fields
};
struct node_data {
   enum node_type type;
   union {
       char *string;
       int i;
       double d;
       struct other_struct other;
    } data;
};
```

Comment: Note: Using uppercase versions of built-in names is not good style. also, as C does not have user-namespaces, the constants should be prefixed with a common name - e.g. `NODE_TYPE_` here.

Answer (score 2):

C is a compiled language. Information about the "type" of a structure or any other variable only exists at compile time, not runtime. If you need polymorphism, you have to implement it yourself.

A common method is to make the first element of a set of structures an indentifier. Either a number (perhaps an index into a table of type info), or something like the address of a type info structure. Then you can assign a pointer any one of those structures, and check that first field to decide what to do with it.

Comment: You're right, but not for exactly the right reason.  C++ is a compiled language which can support runtime type information.  google found https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/RTTI, for example.  C just doesn't support it's a simple language that was designed as portable assembly language.  Stuff that would require extra hidden data or instructions aren't typical in C.

Comment: Yeah, Go has some RTTI as well. That doesn't really fit my idea of what a "fully compiled" language ought to be, but then I'm an old fart.